# Call update function within touchevent

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

Hi I try to create an animation where a circle, in this case named as "ball" become moved by a touchevent and after the user stoptouch the bally become time dependent lesser. After this animation/ touchevent the ball should fall to the bottom like gravity.

```
     function init() {
        bally;
        halfarcx = x * 100;
        halfarcy = (Math.random() * (y * 65)) + y * 10;
        return setInterval(main_loop, 10);


      }
// now come the draw function and after that the funtion who update the arc and who is named update()

    // this function should work like gravity
            function updateball() {
              bally += y *1;

              }


            function main_loop() {
            draw();
            update();


          }


          init();

                    // define startTime variable
            var startTime = 0;

            function initi() {
                console.log('init');

                var touchzone = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

                touchzone.addEventListener("mousedown", startTouch, false);

                touchzone.addEventListener("mouseup", stopTouch, false);
            }

            function startTouch(event) {


                startTime = new Date().getTime();
            }

            function stopTouch(event) {

                var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas");


                if (event.pageX < x * 100 && event.pageY > y * 10) {
                    // Calculate the duration
                    var newtime = new Date().getTime();
                    var duration = newtime - startTime;

                    bally -= 0.005 * duration; 

                    }
                    // there become the function called
                    if (new Date().getTime() >= newtime + 50) {

                    updateball();
                    }




                // I hope bally if defined in the outer scope somewhere ;)                     
                console.log(event, x, bally);
                draw();
            }
                    initi();
                    draw();
```

Now the problem is the "gravity" wont work. What made I wrong or where should I call the function too?

full code: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gu3kjrow/1/)

Comment: I thought thats the relevant code, what do you exactly mean? :)

Comment: But actually you may've been right since it is almost impossible that your interval fired exactly 50 ms after the last saved time, this should be changed to `if (new Date().getTime() >= newtime + 50)` but it won't fix your whole problem.

Comment: Ok thanks, any clue what will fix it?

Comment: a cleanup ? I can't read it properly right now and I am too tired to do it for you. But you're checking if the value of new Date.getTime() is equal to  newTime+50 when newTime was defined just before as Date.getTime().